# PostgreSQL Query for grouping column values into columns

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have the PostreSQL table shown below. `ordered` is a boolean column and `created_at` is a timestamp. I'm trying to fetch rows which tell me the total number of successful orders (`count(t)`) vs failed ordered (`count(f)`) as well as the total number of orders (t + f) grouped by day (extracted from `created_at`)

`ordered | created_at
t        | 2018-10-10 20:13:10
t        | 2018-10-10 21:23:11
t        | 2018-10-11 06:33:52
f        | 2018-10-11 13:13:33
f        | 2018-10-11 19:17:11
f        | 2018-10-12 00:53:01
f        | 2018-10-12 05:14:41
f        | 2018-10-12 16:33:09
f        | 2018-10-13 17:14:14`

I want the following result

`created_at   | ordered_true  | ordered_false | total_orders
2018-10-10   | 2             | 0             | 2
2018-10-11   | 1             | 2             | 3 
2018-10-12   | 0             | 3             | 3
2018-10-13   | 0             | 1             | 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the aggregate functions `sum()` and `count()`:

```
select 
    created_at::date, 
    sum(ordered::int) as ordered_true,
    sum((not ordered)::int) as ordered_false,
    count(*) as total_orders
from my_table
group by 1
order by 1

 created_at | ordered_true | ordered_false | total_orders 
------------+--------------+---------------+--------------
 2018-10-10 |            2 |             0 |            2
 2018-10-11 |            1 |             2 |            3
 2018-10-12 |            0 |             3 |            3
 2018-10-13 |            0 |             1 |            1
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Great, love the idea with the int cast!

Comment: @klin do you know how to do it but from a enum type instead of ordered?

Comment: @Idemax - You probably need `sum(case your_column when 'ordered' then 1 end)` instead of `sum(ordered::int)`. If this doesn't help ask a new question (you can put a link here to let me know).

Comment: @klin i added a question if you have time pls :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71942065/remove-column-from-select-clause-when-using-sum-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT created_at, 
       COUNT(ordered) filter (where ordered = 't') AS ordered_true,
       COUNT(ordered) filter (where ordered = 'f') AS ordered_false, 
       COUNT(*) AS total_orders 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY created_at
```

---

EDIT: use @klint's answer as pointed in the comments by OP grouping by created_at will result in unwanted results as one day will have a couple of groups(timestamp longer than just a day)

Comment: This partly works. `GROUP BY created_at` includes timestamps so I get multiple rows per day. Using `created_at::date` as mentioned by klin solves this issue.